# Conditionally rendering message on HTML page from Typescript in runtime [Angular]

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular. So I may not be able to frame the question correctly. I apologize in advance. I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495960/document-queryselector-is-null-error) question. I have created a login form for my `MEAN stack` application. Its a simple login with `email` and `password` field. My typescript file decides whether the login was successful or not. Here is my code.

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
...

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  flag= {
    valid: true
  }

  ...

  constructor( private _auth: AuthService, private _router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  onSubmit() {
    this._auth.loginUser(this.loginUserData)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        ...
      },
      err => {
        this.flag.valid=false,
        document.querySelector('#login-denied').innerHTML="hello";
      }
    )
  }
}
```

In the above file, `flag` is a boolean variable. True means values are OK and False otherwise.

Here is my html code **login.component.html**

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
      USERNAME FIELD
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      PASSWORD FIELD
  </div>
  <button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>

  <span *ngIf="flag.valid===false" id="login-denied">
      <i class="fa fa-times-circle" style="color:firebrick;"></i>
  </span>
</form>
```

Please pay more attention to my `span` tag. Please correct me. I am getting

> "document.querySelector(...) is null"

And here is a [image: screenshot] also.

As you can see. The `fa` icon is there. But no message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your login component add a string property "message"

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  message: string = '';
  …
}
```

In your submit method

```
onSubmit() {
  this._auth.loginUser(this.loginUserData)
  .subscribe(
    res => {
      ...
    },
    err => {
      this.flag.valid=false,
      this.message = "hello";
    }
  )
}
```

In your html

```
<span *ngIf="!flag.valid" id="login-denied">
  <i class="fa fa-times-circle" style="color:firebrick;">{{message}}</i>
</span>
```

Regards

Comment: It is not recommended to access the DOM directly in angular, since your are bypassing the Angular renderer. This can produce unwanted and unpredictable results.

Answer (score 1):

Why you need to do it with

```
document.querySelector
```

Because you can do it with a variable a variable in angular that would be more proper

```
 error message="";
// When error occurred set the message variable
```

Like this in the error function

```
err => {
        this.flag.valid=false;
this.errorMessage ="Some Error";
        }
```

And bind it in the html like this

```
<span *ngIf="flag.valid===false" id="login-denied">
      <i class="fa fa-times-circle" style="color:firebrick;"></i> {{errorMessage}}
  </span>
```

Comment: I saw this approach somewhere on the internet and it was working for them.