# After clicking button, alert is not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am doing a project on paper-rock-scissor that has UI. So, I have four buttons, *Start game, rock, paper* and *scissor*. I want if I click on the Start game button, an alert ("Please choose rock, paper, or scissor") will pop-up. Right now if I click on the Start game. There's nothing happening. I have no idea why? Below are my code :

-------- HTML code ---------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Project Rock Paper Scissors</title>
        <script src = "javascript.js"> </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button id="startgame"> Start game </button>
            <button id="rock"> Rock </button>
            <button id="paper"> Paper </button>
            <button id="scissor"> Scissor </button>
        </div>    
    </body>

</html>
```

-------- Javascript ----------

```
const startGame = document.querySelector('#startgame');

if (startGame) {
    startGame.addEventListener('click', () => {
        alert("Choose Rock, Paper or Scissor");
    })
}    

const rock = document.querySelector('#rock');
const paper = document.querySelector('#paper');
const scissor = document.querySelector('#scissor');
```

Comment: your document not ready yet maybe

Comment: Check the browser's console to ensure no errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, `startGame` is returning `null`.

### Method 1

In your html code, call javascript code at the end, before closing `<body>` tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Project Rock Paper Scissors</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button id="startgame"> Start game </button>
            <button id="rock"> Rock </button>
            <button id="paper"> Paper </button>
            <button id="scissor"> Scissor </button>
        </div>    

        <script src = "javascript.js"> </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

### Method 2

Add the `defer` attribute to your `<script>` tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Project Rock Paper Scissors</title>
        <script src = "javascript.js" defer> </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button id="startgame"> Start game </button>
            <button id="rock"> Rock </button>
            <button id="paper"> Paper </button>
            <button id="scissor"> Scissor </button>
        </div>    
    </body>

</html>
```

You can look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495960/document-queryselector-is-null-error) question for more information. Credit-Question asker and some answerers. Parts of this answer may have been inspired from them.

Comment: This works, thank you so much ! I learned about the 'defer' previously but only now I am facing the real problem. Thanks